# Why is onShow not working in my angular-strap popover?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popover, angular-strap, event-hooking

I'm developing an AngularJS application that uses Angular-Strap. I'm using the Angular-Strap documentation as a guide:

https://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/

If you follow that link and scroll down to the Popover section, you'll see a table of options, some of which are event handlers. For example, it says that `onShow` is a function that, "if provided, this function will be invoked after the popover is shown."

However, when I try to set the `onShow` handler in my code like this...

```
var popover = $popover($(nameEl), {
    placement: 'top',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    trigger: 'hover',
    content: tooltipHTML,
    onShow: function() {
        console.log('onShow'); 
    }
});
```

...it doesn't respond. I hover over the element it is attached to, I see the popover, but 'onShow' does not print to the console. I put a breakpoint on `console.log('onShow');` and it doesn't get hit.

We're using an older version of Angular-Strap (2.1.3) but I can't seem to find any documentation on this version anywhere, nothing that will tell me whether `onShow` is an event hook for the popover of that version.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for confirming Krampus. There isn't even a message in the console. Would you happen to know if there is an equivalent hook for 2.1.3?